# Service account does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am running Ansible with a service the following configuration which should create a storage bucket on Google Cloud.

```
- name: "Create {{ environ.name }}-cluster-backups"
  google.cloud.gcp_storage_bucket:
    name: "zeipt-io-{{ environ.name }}-cluster-backups"
    location: "{{ google_cloud.region }}"
    storage_class: "NEARLINE"
    lifecycle:
      rule:
        - condition:
            age_days: 28
          action:
            type: "Delete"
    project: "{{ google_cloud.project }}"
    auth_kind: "{{ google_cloud.auth_kind }}"
    service_account_file: "{{ google_cloud.service_account_file }}"
    state: present
```

Which gives the error

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "GCP returned error: {'error': {'code': 403, 'message': 'ansible@staging-environment.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.', 'errors': [{'message': 'ansible@staging-environment.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'forbidden'}]}}"}

I understand the error but I have checked the roles assigned to this user like so

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy staging-environment --flatten="bindings[].members" --format='table(bindings.role)' --filter="bindings.members:ansible@staging-environment.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
ROLE
roles/owner
roles/storage.admin
roles/storage.objectAdmin
roles/storage.objectCreator
roles/storage.objectViewer
```

`roles/storage.admin` should satisfy the requirement as I checked the [Google Cloud IAM Roles page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) which states that this role has the `storage.buckets.*` permission.

I do not understand why I still get the same error?

Comment: Where (desktop, Compute Engine, ...) are you running ansible? If on a compute service, check the scopes enabled for the VM. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam

Comment: @JohnHanley I am running it locally on my mac. I am able to create networks, clusters and much more but not buckets.

Comment: In your command **gcloud projects get-iam-policy** add the command line option **--project PROJECT_ID**. Specify the same project that you are using with Ansible. Maybe you added the correct roles for the wrong project.

Comment: Adding `--project PROJECT_ID` and replacing the name of the same project I have configured in ansible shows the same output. I am starting to think the roles are cached somehow.

Comment: The roles are not cached locally. In Google Cloud, they are globally distributed. Create a new service account and try again. Something simple is being overlooked.

Comment: Is the bucket in the same project? Misspelled bucket name?

Comment: Is your issue resolved @MarkusTenghamn?

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra no I never solved this issue. I had to do this manually because I am not able to use a service account still.

Comment: @JohnHanley Sorry for not replying to you, I am trying to create a bucket so it should not be an issue but I have double check that the service account is in the right project and it's also the project I am running ansible for.

Comment: Can you check if the bucket name you are trying to create already exists?  You can check that in Google Cloud Console > Cloud Storage and enter the bucket name. If it shows an error then I believe that the issue was that you were trying to create/update a bucket owned by a different user belonging to a different project upon which your service account has no power.Therefore please try to redeploy changing the name that likely is a unique one.

Comment: This can be an issue in some scenario because either you choose a very long name or it is not unique. Follow these [guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-buckets) if this is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that some members of the community have offered you some solutions in order to resolve your issue, but apparently none of them has been useful for your issue. Also, I understand that you're using GCP to create the service account and assign the roles.

Maybe you can try to create the service account and the roles for the service account from ansible, and check if that works.

You can create the service account using this plugin [**google.cloud.gcp_iam_service_account – Creates a GCP ServiceAccount**](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_iam_service_account_module.html#google-cloud-gcp-iam-service-account-creates-a-gcp-serviceaccount)

Example:

```
- name: create a service account
  google.cloud.gcp_iam_service_account:
    name: sa-{{ resource_name.split("-")[-1] }}@graphite-playground.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com
    display_name: My Ansible test key
    project: test_project
    auth_kind: serviceaccount
    service_account_file: "/tmp/auth.pem"
    state: present
```

And you can assign the roles using the plugin [**google.cloud.gcp_iam_role – Creates a GCP Role**](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_iam_role_module.html)

Example:

```
- name: create a role
  google.cloud.gcp_iam_role:
    name: myCustomRole2
    title: My Custom Role
    description: My custom role description
    included_permissions:
    - iam.roles.list
    - iam.roles.create
    - iam.roles.delete
    project: test_project
    auth_kind: serviceaccount
    service_account_file: "/tmp/auth.pem"
    state: present
```

Remember that these plugins are part of the **google.cloud collection**, which should be installed if you're using ansible package.

Comment: @Markus Tengham did this answer help you?, if it is this way could you please upvote it or mark it as accepted to help the community? Thanks.